# Permission denied (publickey, password) when running mpiexec using ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, virtual-machine, openssh

I am implementing a simple mpi code. I am using Oracle Virtual box and have
created two Ubuntu vm's one named master and the other named slave. 
Both are connected and can successfully ping each other 
I have followed following step I will describe them one by one.

**Steps**

 I created a folder in the master
`sudo mkdir /mirror` 
This folder is mounted in the slave using `nfs-server`(master) and `nfs-client`(slave) 
 So whatever file I make in master shows up in the slave aswell. 

 
 Then I make user 'mpi' in both master and slave using `sudo adduser --home /mirror --uid 1100 mpi` command 
I log into the mpi user from master and and generate public and private keys using the following command 
 `ssh-keygen -t rsa` which creates .ssh directory in */mirror/.ssh* 
 now because both master and slave share /mirror I go inside /mirror/.ssh via loged in from master in mpi
`cat id_rsa.pub>>authorized_keys` pasting the public key which shows up in slave aswell. 
Then I run `ssh slave` (I can do that becuase I have edited /etc/hosts). This is successful and I get text based interface to slave's shell.

Then in master I run a simple mpi code and I get the following error
[image]

Some other information that I think I should tell 
`/etc/hostname` for master is set to *master* and for slave is set to *slave* 

 the id_rsa.pub file ends with *mpi@appleconda-VirtualBox*

 the sshd_config file properties are 
`PermitRootLogin prohibit-password` 
If you need to know anything else I will tell. I have been stuck on this error for a very long time now. Grateful for help.

Comment: Run `ssh -v -v -v mpi@slave` to see what the problem is at the ssh level.

Comment: Solved the problem was the permission of the /mirror folder which was set to 777 as a security precaution ssh wouldn't allow. Changjng the permissions to 700 solved the problem.